# Rails Server broken after PostgreSQL download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Operating System I am using is Mac OSX Mountain Lion.

First I will give some back story on how this cluster F started. I am going through a Ruby on Rails Web development book. I want to use PostgreSQL as my server. Before today I was using sqlite3. I downloaded PostgreSQL 9.1 from there website. I used the DMG installer. Once I was done with the install process it asked me to re-boot because of some sort of memory problem, I did that and it installed without error.

The problem started when I tried to use the "Rails Server" command in the terminal. This is what I got (I tried to strip out the unimportant stuff which would clutter everything up)

```
/Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/pg-0.12.2/lib/pg.rb:4:in `require': dlopen(/Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/pg-0.12.2/lib/pg_ext.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libcrypto.dylib (LoadError)

Referenced from: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libpq.5.dylib requires version 1.0.0 or later, but libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib provides version 0.9.8 - /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/pg-0.12.2/lib/pg_ext.bundle

...

from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in
```

I have read through the out put and I have done a lot of Google searching, and what I have found is that it's a problem with which version of libcrypto the server is fetching. Or something about the libssl. I have gone through the solutions on google and nothing seems to be working. Hopefully someone has had the same problem I have, and can help me.

Thanks in advance! -Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really recommend you to use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to install postrgresql. It helps you to install all proper dependencies for version which correctly works with rails.

```
$ brew install postgresql
```

Do not forget to follow after install instructions from homebrew

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you installed PostgreSQL server/rubygem successfully?  From the stack trace I think there's a problem about it.

If your PostgreSQL server/rubygem are working well, then switch another webserver, mongrel/thin are both OK, both have better performance than the default rails server(webrick) and easy to use.